# Unity3d mesh is getting distorted while animation

Tags: unity, blender

I attached boxing glove to rig using this method
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719718/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76
 It works fine in the blender, But while animating in unity mesh is getting distorted. 
Image{https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vD80.jpg} 
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Model distorsion is sometimes due to incorrect weightpainting of the mesh. Have you rigged the mesh correctly and  checked the weightpainting for each bone of the skeleton? Oh and is your boxing glove also rigged? Or just the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that you are parenting the boxing glove to the player model(the humanoid). It works fine in blender, but not in unity, probabily due to the weightpaint of the boxing glove in blender. I have in my mind a much easier way of handling this: -import the two models into unity. Drag the player in the scene and look for the hand bone; -create an empty gamobject and attach to this the boxing glove. This way the glove will follow the hand of the player, without actually having to be attached to it in blender.